# Openlayer popup position is the bottom-center

Tags: html, css, popup, openlayers-3

Hi I was working with the OpenLayers 3 popup and I'm trying to center the popup position in the bottom-middle of where I click whatever is width and height and I can't find how I would do that...

I want something dynamic, not base on a predefined height and width.

I create a JSfiddle base on the example of openlayers 3

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hL1cstj5/4/)

It's would be simple if the `left:50%;` work but because it's `position:absolute` it's has no effect.

```
.ol-popup {
  position: absolute;

  ...

  //left:-50%; Doesn't work so I don't know what to do
  left: -50px;
  min-width: 250px;
}
```

Thanks for any anwser

Comment: This should be easy, but I don't know exactly what you need. What's up with original example?

Comment: I want the popup to be like the doubleclick but that appear at the right place not at the right of the click location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
overlay.on('change:position', function(evt) {
  var width=document.getElementsByClassName('ol-popup')[0].offsetWidth;
  var centerX=-width/2;
  var position=[centerX,0];
  this.setOffset(position);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

change your single click listener to this

```
map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
  var coordinate = evt.coordinate;
  var pixel = evt.pixel;
  var hdms = ol.coordinate.toStringHDMS(ol.proj.transform(
      coordinate, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326'));
  var pixelPos = [pixel[0]-(container.offsetWidth/2),pixel[1]-container.offsetHeight];
  var coord = this.getCoordinateFromPixel(pixelPos);
  console.log("coords",coord)
  content.innerHTML = '<p>The arrow is in the middle<br/>And it\'s should pointing where I click (it\'s not the case...)</p><code>' + hdms +
      '</code>';
  overlay.setPosition(coord);
});
```

Also remove the `position:absolute`from your `.ol-popup`css class

Just make sure the function is fired once the container is ready. If you just change your listener function to what I suggest. It wont work on the first click but it should work on every click after the first. Have a look in the code, to get the idea, and adjust it to your case.

check your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hL1cstj5/5/) (as said click twice to see it in action). Or better [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hL1cstj5/6/) without removing position absolute

Comment: It's would work if I don't need to zoom because it's get off the position when you zoom.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center something just use this:

```
.ol-popup {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;     //this will center the div
  top:50%;   

  width: 250px;  //width and height
  height:100px;  


  margin-left:-125px;  //to center the div at the absolute position (half the width)
  margin-top:-50px;  //to center the div at the absolute position (half the height)

  background-color:#000000;  //and a color for the div
}
```

Comment: it would work if I wasn't getting different width and height all time.